# Do negative pressures in Thermodynamics lead to a negative stress energy tensor?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If we have a gas or liquid described by the van der Waals gas law with negative pressure, does that lead to a negative stress energy tensor?
Does a stretched liquid for example have a negative stress energy tensor?

Comment: What do you mean by "negative stress energy tensor"? Elements $T_{ii}$ for $i=1,2,3$ are equal to pressure, so those are negative. Zeroth diagonal component (energy density) need not be negative.

Answer (score 1):

For stable condensed matter, an enthalpic restoring force counteracts any mechanically induced shift in the intermolecular spacing away from the equilibrium spacing.

Put more simply, the matter pushes back under compression and pulls back under tension.

Thus, both modes require mechanical work to be done, and both are associated with a higher energy state, frequently modeled as an [interatomic pair potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interatomic_potential) with a minimum at the equilibrium spacing:

[image]

Mathematically, the energy density is expressed as $E\sim \sigma\varepsilon\sim \sigma^2/K\sim K\varepsilon^2$, where the stress $\sigma$ and strain $\varepsilon$ are either both positive or both negative and where the relevant stiffness $K$ is positive. **In all cases, a positive energy is obtained.**

The case of the van der Waals gas is slightly different. Upon expansion, the entropy benefit outweighs any intermolecular attraction, so expansion is spontaneous; there's no way to hold the gas in tension. There is a repulsion term associated with the finite molecular size, and this repulsion is associated with a higher potential energy.

Comment: Why do you think we don't have an attraction term? Van der Waals equation of state is obtained from the ideal gas law by two modifications; one takes into account excluded volume ($b$), the other decrease of pressure due to inter-molecular attraction ($an^2/V^2$).

Comment: I could have worded that better; please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the stress energy tensor is a 4x4 tensor, where the lower 3x3 form the traditional stress tensor. The first row / column are momentum and energy fluxes. A negative state of stress (tension), generally does not lead to negative energy. In the linear model, the energy density associated with, for example, a pure tension is

$$
e = \frac{\sigma^{2}}{2E}
$$

where $E$ is the elastic modulus of the material.

Regarding your gas law question, I am having a hard time imagining a van der Waals gas in tension. Certainly, other materials can. In fact, strictly speaking thermodynamics should include the state of stress (meaning the full tensor). It is just that in the simplified systems we study in a thermodynamics textbook, the state of stress is always restricted to hydrostatic.